# DFT (FFT) of a Real Even Function Doesn't Yield Real Only DFT Signal

Tags: fft, fourier-transform

There are a lot of similar questions already, but I can't find one answering this problem.

I used the following MATLAB code to perform the FFT on a Lorentzian input signal

```
x = linspace(-10,10,2^10);
y = 1./(x.^2 + 1);
F = fft(y);
IF = imag(F).^2;
power = trapz(IF); %integrating the imaginary part squared
```

Now, from everything I've read, the FFT of a real, even function is supposed to give $0$ imaginary part. But in this case, I get

```
power = 3.86
```

which doesn't seem to be just a small numerical inaccuracy. What's going on here?

Attached is the imaginary spectrum after fftshift.
[image: imaginary spectrum]

Comment: you have to understand that the points $x[0]$ and $x[N/2]$ (where $N$ is the size of the DFT) have no reflected points.  (and remember that silly MATLAB adds 1 to each index.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the DFT matrix is not actually symmetric (hence the FFT is not symmetric). This can be adjusted if you need the symmetry. Modifying your code a bit, here is my session where I use a diagonal matrix D to shift all rows of the DFT matrix to make them explicitly symmetric:

```
x = linspace(-10,10,2^10);
y = 1./(x.^2 + 1);
D = diag(exp(-1j*2*pi*(0:1023)/1024/2));
F = D*fft(y).';
imag(F)'*imag(F) / (F'*F)
   ans =    2.8350e-32
IF = imag(F).^2;
power = trapz(IF)
   power =    2.3315e-27
```

To visualize this, consider the DFT matrix that has a first column of all ones. The last column is $not$ all ones; hence it is not symmetric. By shifting each row by a half step, we get symmetry. The resulting symmetric DFT matrix is still unitary (I think I got this right but please double-check me):

```
V = fliplr(vander(exp(1j*2*pi*(0:(N-1))/N)))';
Vsym = 1/sqrt(N)*diag(sqrt(V(:,2)))*V;
norm(Vsym*Vsym'-eye(1024))
   ans =    2.5503e-13
norm(Vsym'*Vsym-eye(1024))
   ans =    2.5508e-13
```

An alternate solution is to shift your data rather than add a linear phase shift in frequency (i.e. a time shift), meaning that your data needs to not be strictly symmetric into the FFT.

Comment: Ah, that is something peculiar I didn't ​realize. Thanks!

Comment: @HiddenBabel, there's nothing really peculiar.  remember that the FFT is a fast method of evaluating the DFT.  so mathematically, you're dealing with the DFT and all of the properties and theorems of the DFT apply here.  the DFT maps a periodic sequence of length $N$ to another periodic sequence of the same length.  so $$ x[n+N] = x[n] \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{Z} $$ and same for $$ X[k+N] = X[k] \quad \forall k \in \mathbb{Z} $$  if $N$ is odd, everything is symmetrical $X[-k]=X[k]$ for $|k|<N/2$. but if $N$ is even, then $X[-N/2]=X[N/2]$, but they are not two reflected points.

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson I was thinking about the DFT wrongly. I thought that simply distributing points symmetrically around 0 was good enough, but that was wrong. Thanks!

Comment: it's not wrong.  if you come away with this thinking that's wrong, your understanding of the DFT is diminished.

Comment: But that is exactly what I did. The points linspace(-10,10,1024) are symmetrically placed about x=0. However, that doesn't work as we've seen.

Comment: @HiddenBabel, the sequence `x=linspace(-10,10,1025)` is symmetrical about `x(513)` because the number of points is odd.  but the axis of symmetry for `x=linspace(-10,10,1024)` is midway betweem `x(512)` and `x(513)`.  there is no single point of symmetry **unless** you consider `x(1)` and `x(1025)` to be the same value, even though the latter point does not exist.  (all MATLAB indexing, which is fucked.)

Comment: @robert bristow-johnson Yes, what I meant by my comment before is that I thought distributing points around the actual value x=0 was sufficient. I.e. if I have the points [-.75 -.25 .25 .75], those are symmetric about x=0. But as you say, the points must be symmetric about an actual point that exists in the list. Also, I share your hatred of matlab's indexing :)

Comment: if we can ditch MATLAB indexing (and have negative indices), then look at my first comment above. whether $N$ is even or odd, even symmetry of $x[n]$ about $x[0]$ will cause the imaginary values of $X[k]$ to be zero.  but if $N$ is even, you have to *consider* this a split off half of $x[-N/2]$ living at $x[+N/2]$.  originally your even-length sequence goes from $x[-N/2]$ to $x[N/2-1]$ (zeroes everywhere else).  but if you reduce $x[-N/2]$ by a half and take that half your stripped from $x[-N/2]$ and add it to $x[+N/2]$ (which was originally zero), then you've made the whole thing symmetrical.

Comment: This is more about the nuances of the DFT and being familiar with how to manipulate it fit a given purpose. For example, if we want to use radix-2 without wasting any taps, also want zero imaginary in the transform domain, and require linear phase, we may need to play some tricks to achieve this. The latter requirement is a wrinkle for the native form (radix-2, no wasted taps), isn't it? Contrived perhaps, though it may be... ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your x axis goes from -10 to 10 with an even number of samples.  Thus your FFT is probably not symmetric around the 1st sample or N/2 sample in the input vector, which is required for the imaginary part of an FFT result to be (within rounding error of) zero.

<s>Symmetric around the middle only works for odd length FFTs. (try 2^10 + 1)</s>

Try shifting your function half a sample to the left.

Comment: power = 3.8642 (even 2^10)
power = 3.8642 (odd 2^10+1)  first thing I tried

Comment: hotpaw hits it straight up.

Answer (score 0):

When you work with [DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) you need to remember one big assumption of the DFT - The samples are part of periodic signal.

For example, assume your signal in on the grid `vX = [-3:3]`.
Let's say it is the simplest symmetric function: `vY = vX .^ 2`.
If you apply `fft` on it the result won't be real.

Why is that?
Because the `DFT` assumes the input is periodic.
Hence the input signal is something like `[vY, vY, vY, ..., vY]`.

Moreover, for the DFT the indexing is `[0, 1, ..., N - 1]` which in this case is `[0:6]`. Now if we do periodic continuation, what will you get on the grid of `[-7:6]`?

```
figure();
plot([-7:6], [vY, vY]);
```

It won't be a be symmetric around 0 (Of course look at `[-6, 6]`).

Let's define `vYY = vY(1:6)`.
If you apply `fft(vYY)` the result is pure real.
Why is that?
Because for the DFT it sits on the grid `[0:5]`.
If you plot a periodic continuation of it:

```
figure();
plot([-6:5], [vYY, vYY]);
```

Look on `[-5, 5]`, now it is symmetric.
Hence its DFT is pure real.

### MATLAB Code

```
% The Grid
vX = [-3:3];
vY = vX .^ 2; %<! Even Function on the Grid

figure();
plot(vX, vY);
title('Figure 001');

vYDft = fft(vY);
norm(imag(vYDft), 'inf')

norm(imag(fft(vY(1:6))), 'inf')

figure();
plot([-7:6], [vY, vY])
title('Figure 002');

figure();
plot([-6:5], [vY(1:6), vY(1:6)]);
title('Figure 003');
```

Output:

> `ans = 7.2678`
>   `ans = 0`

Figure 001

[image]

Figure 002

[image]

Figure 003

[image]

Answer (score -1):

try

```
x = linspace(10*(-1024/1024), 10*(1023/1024), 2048);
y = 1./(x.^2 + 1);
y = fftshift(y);
Y = fft(y);
max(abs(imag(Y)))/mean(abs(Y))
```

i didn't run this, but i bet the number that appears at bottom is very very tiny.  like around `1e-15` .

Comment: Let's not change out metric, power =
    0.9666,   better  , but still higher than I expected

Comment: i don't understand what you mean, Stan.

Comment: whoops, have to modify this a teeny bit

Comment: we should stick to the same error metric, power = trapz(IF); %integrating the imaginary part squared

Comment: i have no idea what `trapz()` is.  but the **maximum** value of the imaginary part relative to the mean abs value of the whole thing (since this is in floating point) is a good worst case metric.  we could replace both with $\sqrt{ \ \overline{| \cdot |^2} \ }$ but that would hide the maximum errors.

Comment: >> help trapz. might try that.  It’s just about apples to apples.  The Op used a metric. The question didn’t ask for a metric. Do you have any objections to a systematic consistent Engineering process?  At this point, I don’t want to waste my time.  Feel completely free to interject extraneous elements.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was tagged as not helpful. The point here is that the input waveform is slightly asymmetric to match the asymmetry of the fft. All of the points other than index 0 and N/2 are paired up symmetrically so that the imaginary part goes to zero (or very close to it). I believe this is the lowest cost method to get to zero imaginary.

Comment: i don't think Stan liked it.